# Rejoining farm and site can’t reached

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I’ve multi SharePoint 2016 Server WFE, APP, Search & DB. Cause so many issue, I decided to disconnected all of them from farm.

After that, I rejoining them to the existing farm (previous farm not deleted) and everything is working fine including the Central Administration but the Site showed error message **“Site can’t be reached”**.

CA possible to access from internet and intranet, but for the Site is not. Please note, the Site is accessible from the internet before I disconnected.

[image: CA accessed from my Phone (Internet)]

[image: Site accessed from my Phone (Internet)]

Hope you guys have a solutions. I’ll appreciate it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try a different browser.

If you are using chrome you can fix it by referring to the following article:

https://www.ghacks.net/2016/08/26/fixing-microsoft-site-cant-be-reached-error-in-chrome/

There's a similar situation here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d828429a-512f-48d1-b56c-d657551d309f/spweb-amp-spsite-this-site-can8217t-be-reached?forum=sharepointadmin

If the problem persists, check uls log to see if there is any relevant error information.